# Eclipse tries to open files in the project via web browser

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a database(database.json) in my asset folder. Whenever I try to reach it in code, eclipse tries to open it in the web browser therefore it returns **null**.

Here is a code sample of my problem.

```
 public class JsonDBparse extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_json_dbparse);
        JSONObject db   = parse("file:///android_asset/database.json");
        JSONObject shop = parse("file:///android_asset/shop.json");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) db, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Whenever I use CTRL+Click on

```
    "file:///android_asset/database.json"
```

Eclipse opens the web browser and assumes the file path is a URI.
How can I reach my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("database.json");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
JSONObject db   = parse(file.toString());
```

this works.